How to bypass server restrictions for downloading a file due to CORS policy?
I am working on a Flutter application, and I need to download a ZIP file from a public server using an HTTP GET request. The URL is something like: "https://example.com/file.zip".
However, when I try to download the file from the web version of my app, the browser blocks the request due to CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) restrictions. The server does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in its response.
Here’s the basic structure of my current code:
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:html' as html;
// import 'dart:io';

Future<void> downloadZipFileWidget() async {
  const String url = 'https://example/file.zip';
  const String savePath = 'file.zip';
  try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         final fileBytes = response.bodyBytes;
      print('File downloaded successfully');
        createDownloadLink(fileBytes, savePath);
             print('File saved to $savePath');
    } else {
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}

void createDownloadLink(List<int> bytes, String fileName) {
  final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
  final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
  final anchor = html.AnchorElement(href: url)
  ..target = 'blank'
  ..download = fileName
  ..click();
  html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
}

And I call to the function from another ".dart" file.
when running on the web, I encounter the CORS issue.
Question:
What are the best ways to bypass CORS restrictions for downloading files in a Flutter Web app?
Are there proxy services, or should I implement my own proxy server?
Is there any way to work directly with the server without needing CORS modifications?


If the server doesn't include CORS headers, then you have no choice but to proxy the request. You will be serving your Flutter web app from somewhere, and that's where you need to add an additional endpoint to proxy the download. (You won't have a CORS issue because the download endpoint will be on the same server as the app serving URL.) If your server supports Dart, you can use shelf and shelf_static to serve the app and implement your proxy.
